# Silverlight Signing

Tags: silverlight

I wanted to sign my silverlight application. Followed these 2 links but I still get unverified.
WHen I double click on the pfx file and the cer file, it told me import successful.
But when I install as OOB, I still get unverified.

Tried using the default VS2010 signing by creating a Test Cert, but still same problem.

http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/alexb/archive/2010/05/10/silverlight-4-digitally-signing-a-xap.aspx

http://johnpapa.net/silverlight/digitally-signing-a-xap-silverlight/

When i look under the certificate details, I always see something like this link.
https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=745

Is there some steps I missed out?